# Discrete logarithm modulo powers of a small prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, algorithms, modular-arithmetic, computational-complexity

Is there an efficient way to compute $x$ in $2^x \equiv b \pmod {p^m}$, where $p$ is a small odd prime and $m$ could be a large integer? I know the solution is of the form $x=\phi(p^m) k + y$ for arbitrary non-negative integer $k$, but I don't know how to compute $y$ efficiently.

For example, solution of $2^x\equiv 28 \pmod {3^5}$ is given by $x=(2 \times 3^4) k + 72$ since $2^{(2 \times 3^4)k}\equiv 1 \pmod{3^5}$ by Euler/Carmichael's theorem and $2^{72}\equiv 28 \pmod{3^5}$. I don't know how to compute that $72$ other than generalized methods for solving discrete logarithm.

PS. By "efficient" I mean an algorithm whose complexity is hopefully polynomial in $p$ and $m$, but I accept answers which are more efficient than generalized methods of solving discrete logarithm.

Comment: If you want to look ahead, the "lifting" scheme is outlined in Section 4 of [Discrete Logarithms and Factoring](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1984/CSD-84-186.pdf) by Eric Bach (1984).  I'm working on a concise exposition.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. My question is answered completely in that reference. The reference is very clear and concise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When $p$ is a *small* prime, finding a solution to $a^x \equiv b \bmod p$ is correspondingly easy (assuming that $a,b$ are not divisible by $p$).  For example, $2^x \equiv 28 \bmod 3$ holds for any even power $x$.

It is also clear that if $a^x \equiv b \bmod p^s$ for some integer power $s\ge 1$, then:

$$ a^x \equiv b \bmod p^s \implies a^x \equiv b \bmod p^{s-1} \implies \ldots \implies a^x \equiv b \bmod p $$

Eric Bach (1984) wrote up [a polynomial time algorithm](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1984/CSD-84-186.pdf), similar to the ideas of [Hensel lifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#Hensel_Lifting) for polynomials, to work backwards in that chain of implications.  His purpose was to compare the difficulty of solving the discrete logarithm problem for a general modulus $n$ with that of factoring $n$, so we here are concerned only with a portion of his work.

As usual $\mathbb{Z}$ is the integers, and $\mathbb{Z}_n$ will denote the ring of integers modulo $n$.  The additive group of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ will be written as $\mathbb{Z}_n^+$, while the multiplicative group of its units is written $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$.  Note that the additive group is cyclic and has $n$ elements, while the number of elements in the multiplicative group is given by [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\varphi(n)$ (counting the integers $0\lt k \lt n$ which are coprime to $n$).

Taking the case where $n = p^s$ is a prime power $s\ge 1$, the counting is easy:

$$ \varphi(p^s) = (p-1)p^{s-1} $$

Is the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_{p^s}^*$ *cyclic* of that order?  In the case that $p$ is an *odd* prime, the [answer is yes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373708/when-is-the-group-of-units-in-mathbbz-n-cyclic), and a generator for this group is called a [primitive root modulo *n*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n).

For this reason Bach begins with the case of an odd prime $p$, and thus we know an isomorphism:

$$ \mathbb{Z}_{p^s}^* \cong \mathbb{Z}_p^* \times \mathbb{Z}_{p^{s-1}}^+ $$

It is easy to find the projection of $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{p^s}^*$ onto the first factor: just take the reduction of $k \bmod p$.

It is the essence of the rest of the algorithm to show a polynomial-time computable projection $\theta$ from multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_{p^s}^*$ homomorphically onto the second factor, additive group $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{s-1}}^+$:

$$ \theta: \mathbb{Z}_{p^s}^* \to \mathbb{Z}_{p^{s-1}}^+ $$

Once we have this function, the "lifting" of a solution mod $p$:

$$ a^{x_1} \equiv b \bmod p $$

to one in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^s}^*$:

$$ a^{x_s} \equiv b \bmod p^s $$

proceeds in a fairly natural way.  Note that $x_s \equiv x_1 \bmod (p-1)$.

Applying the projection $\theta$ to the above "higher order" congruence leads us to this problem in the *additive group* $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{s-1}}^+$:

$$ c \cdot \theta(a) \equiv \theta(b) \bmod p^{s-1} $$

which can be solved by reciprocating $\theta(a)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{s-1}}$ via the extended Euclidean algorithm.

If we find an integer $x_s$ by [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) such that both:

$$ x_s \equiv x_1 \bmod (p-1) $$
$$ x_s \equiv c \bmod p^{s-1} $$

then we are done, because by the isomorphism:

$$ a^{x_s} \equiv b \bmod p^s $$

Bach gives this formula for the homomorphism $\theta:\mathbb{Z}_{p^s}^*\to \mathbb{Z}_{p^{s-1}}^+$:

$$ \theta(k) = \left[ \frac{k^{(p-1)p^{s-1}} - 1}{p^s} \right] \bmod p^{s-1} $$

Details of why this is a homomorphism from the multiplicative group to the additive one are given in Bach's paper.  Certainly $\theta(1) = 0$, and as I find time, I'll add further proof.

As Bach notes, the complexity of this function is polynomial in $\log p$ and $s$ if the numerator (of the integer expression inside the square brackets) is evaluated mod $p^{2s-1}$.  We need that many radix $p$ places to get the right residue mod $p^{s-1}$ after dividing by $p^s$. The exactness of the division is implied by [Euler's generalization of Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

**Example** (taken from the Question)

Consider the equation $2^x \equiv 28 \bmod 3^5$.  As already remarked above, any even integer $x$ solves the "base case" $2^x \equiv 28 \bmod 3$.  Therefore we will get a second congruence to combine with the first one:

$$ x \equiv 0 \bmod (3-1) $$
$$ x \cdot \theta(2) \equiv \theta(28) \bmod 3^4 $$

Recall that computing $\theta(k)$ involves raising to the power $\varphi(3^5) = 2\cdot 3^4 = 162$.  A [minimal additive chain for exponents](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/addition_chain.html) leading to $162$ has nine steps.  The binary one attains this by repeated squaring, doubling exponent to $128$, followed by multiplications of intermediate values that add to the exponent:

$$ 162 = 128 + 32 + 2 $$

In any case the values are small enough to do by calculator and to check with a spreadsheet:

$$ \theta(2) \equiv \left[ \frac{2^{162}-1}{243} \right] \equiv 16 \bmod 81 $$

$$ \theta(28) \equiv \left[ \frac{28^{162}-1}{243} \right] \equiv 18 \bmod 81 $$

Thus the second congruence amounts to:

$$ 16x \equiv 18 \bmod 81 $$
$$ 80x \equiv 90 \bmod 81 $$
$$ -x \equiv 9 \bmod 81 $$
$$ x \equiv 72 \bmod 81 $$

Since $x=72$ is already even, this is our solution modulo $2\cdot 3^4$.

TO DO: Fill in the details for the exceptional "even prime" case $p=2$.

Comment: Let me know if you are still working on this. If not, I can give pseudocode based on the results derived in that paper.

Comment: @mhp: If you'd like to post an Answer giving the pseudocode, and perhaps some words about the application or other motivation for your Question, that may benefit future Readers.

Comment: Thank you for completing your answer. I don't think there is any need for a pseudocode at this point.