# General rule to say that $(\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups

**Definition:** $(\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z})^{\times} = \{\bar{a} \in \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}: \gcd(a, n) = 1\}$.

I know that $(\mathbb{Z}/9 \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/6 \mathbb{Z}))^{\times}$ are cyclic because $\langle\bar{5}\rangle = (\mathbb{Z}/9 \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and $ \langle\bar{2}\rangle = (\mathbb{Z}/6 \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, but $(\mathbb{Z}/8 \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is not cyclic. Is there a general rule to say if $(\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is cyclic?

Comment: cf: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n

Comment: Use `\times` instead of `X` and `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>`.

Comment: This question has been many times before: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314846/for-what-n-is-u-n-cyclic), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373708/when-is-the-group-of-units-in-mathbbz-n-cyclic), for instance. Please search before asking a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes: $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic if and only if $n$ is either an odd-prime power, or $2p^n$ with odd prime $p$.

One direction of the proof is relatively easy, since $\mathbb Z/p^mq^n\mathbb Z\approx \mathbb Z/p^m\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/q^n\mathbb Z$... making it hard for the multiplicative group to be cyclic.

The prime-power case is slightly subtler, and the factor-of-$2$ aspect also.

EDIT: and, as @lhf reminded me, for $m=1,2,4$! :)

Comment: Also, $n=1,2,4$.