# Find out $\mathrm{Aut}\ \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Prove that 
$$\mathrm{Aut}\ \mathbb{Z}_{2^n}=\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_{2^{n-2}}$$
$$\mathrm{Aut}\ \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}=\mathbb{Z}_{p^{n-1}(p-1)}$$

I figured out that $\mathrm{Aut}\ \mathbb{Z}_n=U(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ and $\lvert U(\mathbb{Z}_n) \rvert=\varphi(n)$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler's totient function, how should I go on?

Comment: Can you find generators?

Comment: Is your question really why are the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ cyclic?

Comment: @Nex yes that's part of the question when p is odd prime number

Comment: @MichaelBurr I have no clue how to find generators:(

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73498/is-the-group-of-units-of-a-finite-ring-cyclic