# On the multiplicative group of units of quotients of rings of integers in number fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

In the thread below a reference to a paper (published in American Journal of Math) classifying finite rings with a cyclic group of units is given.

The finite ring $R_l:=\mathbb{Z}/2^l\mathbb{Z}$ is not on this list (for $l=3$ you may check that the group of units $(R_l)^*\cong \mathbb{Z}/(2)\times \mathbb{Z}/(2)$ is non-cyclic). Has the group of units $R_l^*$ of $R_l$ been classified?

More generally if $K$ is a number field and $I \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$ is an ideal, there is a factorization $I=\mathfrak{m}_1^{l_1}\cdots \mathfrak{m}_d^{l_d}$ into a product of distinct maximal ideals. This leads to the following question: Is the multiplicative group of units $(\mathcal{O}_K/I)^* \cong \oplus_i (\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}_i^{l_i})^*$ known for any such ideal $I$?

[Is the group of units of a finite ring cyclic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73498/is-the-group-of-units-of-a-finite-ring-cyclic/73503#comment8833399_73503)

Comment: Yes, it's a standard result that this group is isomorphic to Z/2 x Z/2^(l-2)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Powers_of_2, the answer is that
$$
(\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})^\times \cong \mathrm{C}_2 \times \mathrm{C}_{2^{k-2}}
$$

Comment: Thanks, I altered the question - if you have references to this new question, post a response.

Comment: @hm2020 I'd recommend posting your new question as a new question so it gets seen, I'm not sure I know a reference, but I imagine the answer is something similar that for each maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ there is some $n_{\mathfrak m}$ (depending on the ramification of the prime?) and all $i>n_{\mathfrak m}$ we have $(\mathcal O/\mathfrak m^i)^*\cong (\mathcal O/\mathfrak m^{n_\mathfrak m})^* \times Cyclic$

Answer (score 1):

We have the following result:

> The group of units $(\mathbf Z/2^l\mathbf Z)^{\times}\:(l\ge 2)$  is generated by the internal direct product of the subgroup of order $2$ defined by the congruence class of $-1$ and the subgroup of order $2^{l-2}$ generated by the congruence class of $5$.

If you read french, you can find a proof on [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anneau_%E2%84%A4/n%E2%84%A4).